# OpenOptions write not working properly when writing to file

Tags: file, rust

So I'm learning rust by making a simple cat/bat clone in rust, and I can't seem to overwrite a file.


**Code**:

```
use std::{fs::*, io::{Read, Write}};

fn main() {
    let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .write(true)
        .open("foo.txt")
        .unwrap();
    
    let mut contents = String::new();
    let mut formatted = String::new();

    file.read_to_string(&mut contents).unwrap();

    let mut i = 0;
    let mut formatted_line:String;

    for line in contents.split("\n") {
        formatted_line = format!("{}| {}",i,line);
        formatted.push_str(&formatted_line);
        i += 1;
    }

    file.write_all(formatted.as_bytes()).unwrap();
}
```

foo.txt before:

```
test
foo
bar
```

foo.txt after:

```
test
foo
bar0| test
1| foo
2| bar
```

Based on what I've read, and what's in the documentation in `fs.rs:747-748`:

```
/// If the file already exists, any write calls on it will overwrite its
/// contents, without truncating it.
```

the `.write(true)` option specifies **overwriting** file content, and the `.append(true)` option appends to the existing content. But from the code I wrote, the program is ignoring the write OpenOption, and appending to the file contents. I also tried `.append(false)` on the OpenOptions, and same output.

I'm using Windows 10 Home, and foo.txt is a txt file with no special permissions or restrictions of any sort.

Rust / Cargo Versions:

`rustc 1.55.0 (c8dfcfe04 2021-09-06)`

`cargo 1.55.0 (32da73ab1 2021-08-23)`

Comment: but your read the file entirely... use https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html#method.rewind before write so

Comment: @Stargateur Ah okay, I get it. I didn't know that it used the same stream for reading and writing. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I suggest writing the result to a new file instead. If you really want to operate in place, the most robust approach is writing to a temporary file first, and moving the temporary file to the original location once it's fully written. This allows streaming reads and writes, so you don't need to keep the full file contents in memory at once, and it also minimizes the chances of leaving things in a half-completed state when I/O errors occur. (On Unix-derived operating systems, i.e. not Windows, moving the temp file to the original location is an atomic operation.)

Comment: Overwriting doesn't mean you're overwriting the entire content of a file. Say your file has 8 `A`s in it, then you write 3 `X`s into to the buffer with the `write(true)` argument supplied, you have now overwritten the first 3 `A`s, meaning your file now contains `XXXAAAAA`, see, your overwrote some data (example taken from [here](https://ddanilov.me/how-to-overwrite-a-file-in-rust)). Rust doesn't automatically truncate (remove file contents without removing the file) the file, for that you need to also call `truncate(true)`.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, using rust 1.67.1. I'm trying to non-additively write to a text file just like you are. Here's how I instantiated the file object:

```rust
let mut output_txt_file = OpenOptions::new().create_new(true).write(true).append(false).open(output_txt_filename).unwrap();
```

but when I call `write()` multiple times, I get multiple lines of input instead of just the most recent one. Crazy that several years later this bug still hasn't been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would better use simple fs::*, as i know, OpenOptions if you will create multiprocess/thread code this function will face with races, so possible(as i understood: read all then delete all and write):

```
use std::fs::{File, write};
use std::io::Result;

fn main() -> Result<()>{
let mut file = File::open("foo.txt")?;
//Read(create copy if you need something simultaneous read before)
// file.try_clone()?;//simply, both files changes 
file.read_to_end(&mut your_string_or_vec)?;
//..... Your code
//and then truncate all
file_copy.set_len(0)?;
write("foo.txt", formatted.as_bytes())?;
}
```

Another approach to take temporary file(the place of one isn't important(`std::env::temp_dir()`))

```
use std::fs::{File, write};
use tempfile::NamedTempFile;
use std::io:: Result;

fn main() -> Result<()>{
let mut read_from_file = String::new();
let mut formatted = String::new();

read_from_file = fs::read_to_string("foo.txt")?.parse()?;
for line in read_from_file.split("\n") {
        formatted_line = format!("{}| {}",i,line);
        formatted.push_str(&formatted_line);
        i += 1;
    }

let mut file_tmp1 = NamedTempFile::new()?;
println!("Let's write into temporary {:?}", file.path());

let mut file_tmp2 = file_tmp1.reopen()?;
writeln!(file_tmp1, formatted)?;

let mut buf = String::new();
file_tmp2.read_to_string(&mut buf)?;

fs::write("foo.txt",buf.as_bytes())?;
file_tmp1.close()?;
file_tmp2.close()?;
```